# Kohana and ORM relationship has_many_through

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I have problem with Kohana 3.3 and ORM relationship has_many_through. I have two models

**Model_Category**

```
class Model_Category extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'category';
    protected $_primary_key = 'category_id';
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'question' => array(
            'model' => 'Question',
            'through' => 'cat_question'
        ),
    );

}
```

**Model_Question**

```
class Model_Question extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'question';
    protected $_primary_key = 'question_id';
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'category' => array(
            'model' => 'Category',
            'through' => 'cat_question'
        ),
    );

}
```

- And in table `cat_question` there are two columns, `category_id, question_id`,
- in table `question`: `question_id, title, content, date`,
- in `category`: `category_id, name`

But it's not working preety good.. When i do it like that

```
$orm = ORM::factory('Question')->find_all();
foreach($orm as $el) {
    var_dump($el->category->name);
}
```

They shows me NULL, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I handle with this, 
Question model should be looks like that :

```
class Model_Question extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'question';
    protected $_primary_key = 'question_id';

     protected $_has_many = array(
        'category' => array(
            'model' => 'Category',
            'through' => 'cat_question',
            'far_key' => 'category_id',
            'foreign_key' => 'question_id',
            ),
    );
  }
```

And Category models

```
class Model_Category extends ORM {

    protected $_table_name = 'category';
    protected $_primary_key = 'category_id';


    protected $_has_many = array(
        'question' => array(
            'model' => 'Question', 
            'far_key' => 'question_id',
            'through' => 'cat_question',
            'foreign_key' => 'category_id'
            ),
    );

}
```

And if we want all category with count question is in, do something like that:

```
  public function get_category_and_question() {
        $orm = ORM::factory('Category');
        $find = $orm->find_all();
        foreach ($find as $element) {
            $count = ORM::factory('Category', $element->category_id)->question->count_all();
            $new_array[] = array(
                'name' => $element->name,
                'id' => $element->category_id,
                'how_much' => $count
            );
        }
        return $new_array;
    }
```

I'm not pretty sure if that is really good solve but is not bad for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that has_many_through means many-to-many. So one Category holds multiple Questions and vice versa. Now if you had followed Kohana's standards, your db name would be `categories, questions, categories_questions` and the name would be a plural, so accessible via `categories` or `questions`.

But you didn't, to work your code needs to look like the following

```
$orm = ORM::factory('Question')->find_all();
foreach($orm as $el)
{
    $categories = $el->category->find_all();
    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        var_dump($category->name);
    }
}
```